# ArgumentError: FROM expression expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter

I have the following cell in jupyter notebook. What is in ***** is confidential information

```
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pds
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create an engine instance
alchemyEngine   = create_engine('*****************************', pool_recycle=3600);
# engine = create_engine('**************************')

# Connect to PostgreSQL server
dbConnection    = alchemyEngine.connect();

# Read data from PostgreSQL database table and load into a DataFrame instance
team = sa.Table('dialog_logger', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=dbConnection, schema='hca')

qry = sa.select(team.c.hos_name, team.c.hos_id, team.c.datetime, team.c.patient_cel_number,
                team.c.hospital_cel_number, team.c.message, team.c.direction).where(
                team.c.datetime > '2022-11-01 00:00:00').where(team.c.datetime < '2022-11-30 00:00:00')


dataFrame_argentina  = pds.read_sql_query(qry, dbConnection)

pds.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False);


# Close the database connection

dbConnection.close();
```

I must execute it but it gives me the following error when doing it:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    722         try:
--> 723             return getattr(self.comparator, key)
    724         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'selectable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py in _interpret_as_from(element)
     60     try:
---> 61         return insp.selectable
     62     except AttributeError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    726                 "Neither %r object nor %r object has an attribute %r"
--> 727                 % (type(self).__name__, type(self.comparator).__name__, key)
    728             )

AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ec4194d4c35c> in <module>
      1 qry = sa.select(team.c.hos_name, team.c.hos_id, team.c.datetime, team.c.patient_cel_number,
----> 2                 team.c.hospital_cel_number, team.c.message, team.c.direction).where(
      3                 team.c.datetime > '2022-11-01 00:00:00').where(team.c.datetime < '2022-11-30 00:00:00')
      4 
      5 

<string> in select(columns, whereclause, from_obj, distinct, having, correlate, prefixes, suffixes, **kwargs)

<string> in __init__(self, columns, whereclause, from_obj, distinct, having, correlate, prefixes, suffixes, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py in warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    126                     )
    127 
--> 128             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    129 
    130         doc = fn.__doc__ is not None and fn.__doc__ or ""

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py in __init__(self, columns, whereclause, from_obj, distinct, having, correlate, prefixes, suffixes, **kwargs)
   2977         if from_obj is not None:
   2978             self._from_obj = util.OrderedSet(
-> 2979                 _interpret_as_from(f) for f in util.to_list(from_obj)
   2980             )
   2981         else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py in __init__(self, d)
    363         self._list = []
    364         if d is not None:
--> 365             self._list = unique_list(d)
    366             set.update(self, self._list)
    367         else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py in unique_list(seq, hashfunc)
    777     seen_add = seen.add
    778     if not hashfunc:
--> 779         return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
    780     else:
    781         return [

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    777     seen_add = seen.add
    778     if not hashfunc:
--> 779         return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
    780     else:
    781         return [

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2977         if from_obj is not None:
   2978             self._from_obj = util.OrderedSet(
-> 2979                 _interpret_as_from(f) for f in util.to_list(from_obj)
   2980             )
   2981         else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py in _interpret_as_from(element)
     61         return insp.selectable
     62     except AttributeError:
---> 63         raise exc.ArgumentError("FROM expression expected")
     64 
     65 

ArgumentError: FROM expression expected
```

Debugging I saw that everything runs fine until this select starts: qry = sa.select(......).
I don't know if the error comes from the library that I need to install before executing this cell.

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you using ?

Comment: I mention this because the usage of `select()` has been changing.  I'm not sure your usage is supported in `sqlalchemy<1.4`.

Comment: when executing conda list it tells me that I have sqlalchemy 1.3.13

Answer (score 1):

You still have some debugging work ahead of you.

Take a look at the columns: `team.c`

- Verify spellings.
- Put each column (like "hos_name") on its own line, so it can easily be `#` commented out.
- Simplify the query. Start with an easy query of just a single column, and build up from there until you encounter breakage.
- Remove both filters, and add them back one-by-one.

Tackling it methodically in that way will soon show you the mismatch
between code and table.

Everything looks good to me.
But then, I cannot view e.g. `SELECT * FROM dialog_logger` output.
I usually spell it .filter() rather than .where() -- whatever,
prolly works much the same.

BTW, `print(qry)` will show you the rendered SQL query,
which can sometimes shed a bit of light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sqlalchemy 1.3.13 suports that usage.  Try this, note the columns are in a list, this changes in 1.4 and beyond:

```py
# THIS IS FOR sqlalchemy < 1.4 ONLY!!!
qry = sa.select([team.c.hos_name, team.c.hos_id, team.c.datetime, team.c.patient_cel_number,
                team.c.hospital_cel_number, team.c.message, team.c.direction]).where(
                team.c.datetime > '2022-11-01 00:00:00').where(team.c.datetime < '2022-11-30 00:00:00')
```

I think your exception is related to the fact that the 3rd argument in the **old** `select()` function is expected to be a `from_obj` and not just another column: [OLD select()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html?highlight=select#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select)

I'm putting this warnings about 1.3/1.4 so people don't come here and try the same queries in 1.4+.  I understand if you can't upgrade because of the 3rd party tools.

Comment: thanks man, that was the problem, adding the columns inside the list I solve the error